# Python, SelectKBest doesn't work

Tags: python, feature-selection

I use `SelectKBest` to select the most important features in my data set, but the length of `X_new` is the same as the length of  `X`.

here is my simple code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
X=[[1,4,3,5],[4,5,4,5],[6,3,8,3],[6,3,10,7]]
Y=[1,1,2,2]
X_new = SelectKBest(k=2).fit_transform(X, Y)
len(X_new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the desired result. `SelectKBest(k=2)` is taking the best 2 features from each set in `X`, based on the values provided in `Y`.

After giving twice the value for the last 2 values, the `SelectKBest` is picking the *2nd* and *3rd* elements in each set, which gives

```
[[ 4  3]
 [ 5  4]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 3 10]]
```

This is exactly what you are supposed to get :). The resulting array is of length 4 (same as `X`) since it picks from each set the top 2 elements. `SelectKBest` should result in a new array *Number_of_sets_in_input_array*  * *K*. In your case it is 4*2 (as `X` is a 4*4 array, and you chose `k=2`)